# Optimize SQL "SELECT .. LIMIT" with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization

I've got two tables: "users" and "purchase". I've wrote this simple SELECT query and it worked fine but a very long time. I want to optimize my query. I found a lot of examples how to do that but there were no ex (or I didn't find that) with selecting and comparing the data from two tables. Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
    purchase.user, purchase.price, users.login, users.id 
FROM 
    purchase, users 
WHERE 
    (purchase.user = users.id) AND (purchase.active = 1) 
ORDER BY purchase.time 
DESC LIMIT $page * $per_page, 15
```

Comment: Did you try to run an [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) against your query for a start?

Answer (score 0):

There can be any number of reasons why it is slow.  Here are just some.

1. You just have a LOT of data (millions).
2. No indexes.  Check your indexes on the tables.  Do you have them defined?
3. Bad Clause.  Try it without certain clauses (eg. without DESC, without ORDER)
4. Hardware issues (it's stored somewhere with a really slow disk.)
5. A "very long time" is different for you and me.

Comment: There are few thousands in users and purchase. It takes an about 15 seconds to display one page

Comment: A "long time" with OFFSET 0?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`